# NumPy ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all() leastsq

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, ipython, least-squares

```
from sympy import *
from scipy import *
from scipy.integrate import quad
import scipy.optimize as optimize
import numpy as np
import collections
import math
from scipy.optimize import leastsq

file= DATA+'Union21.dat'
with open(file, "r") as f:
    data0=[(float(v[1]),float(v[2]), float(v[3])) for v in [x.split() for x in f.readlines()][1:]]
#print data0

z=np.array([float(t[0]) for t in data0])
mu=np.array([float(t[1]) for t in data0])
dmu=np.array([float(t[2]) for t in data0])
c=3*10^8

def calka(x, OmM):
    return 1./math.sqrt(OmM*(1.+x)**3 + (1.-OmM))

def xlambda(p,xup): 
    H0=p
    calka1 = quad(calka, 0., xup, args=(p[0]))[0]
    mu_obs = 5.*math.log(c*calka1/p[1]) + 25 
    return mu_obs


def residuals(p, xup,y,dmu):
    return ((y-xlambda(p,xup))/dmu)**2

leastsq(residuals,(0.25, 70), args=(z, mu, dmu))
```

Thank you for your answer but now there was a problem:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call     last)
TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('complex128') to     dtype('float64') according to the rule 'safe'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call     last)
<ipython-input-38-00c118ea80ce> in <module>()
----> 1 leastsq(residuals,[0.25, 70], args=(z, mu, dmu))

/opt/anaconda/envs/np18py27-1.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy    /optimize/minpack.pyc in leastsq(func, x0, args, Dfun, full_output,     col_deriv, ftol, xtol, gtol, maxfev, epsfcn, factor, diag)
377             maxfev = 200*(n + 1)
378         retval = _minpack._lmdif(func, x0, args, full_output, ftol, xtol,
--> 379                                  gtol, maxfev, epsfcn, factor, diag)
380     else:
381         if col_deriv:

error: Result from function call is not a proper array of floats.
```

I try change dtype array from complex128 to float64 but it didn't help :(

I looking for maybe np.interp but i don't know which array a i must change

Can you any idea what i have to do?

Answer (score 4):

The error message can be reproduced like this:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as integrate

xup = np.random.random(10)

def calka(x, OmM):
    return 1./math.sqrt(OmM*(1.+x)**3 + (1.-OmM))


# Passing a scalar value, 10, for the upper limit is fine:
integrate.quad(calka, 0., 10, args=(0.25,))
# (2.3520760256393554, 1.9064918795817483e-12)

# passing a vector, xup, raises a ValueError:
integrate.quad(calka, 0., xup, args=(0.25,))
# ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

---

Now, in your code, `z` is an array:

```
z=np.array([float(t[0]) for t in data0])
```

`z` gets passed to `residuals`:

```
leastsq(residuals,(0.25, 70), args=(z, mu, dmu))
```

Inside `residuals`, `xup` gets assigned the value `z`.

```
def residuals(p, xup,y,dmu):
    return ((y-xlambda(p,xup))/dmu)**2
```

Inside `xlambda`, `xup` -- the vector -- is passed directly to `quad`:

```
def xlambda(p,xup): 
    H0=p
    calka1 = quad(calka, 0., xup, args=(p[0]))[0]
```

Hence the ValueError.

---

Presumably, you'd want `xlambda` to be called once for each value in `xup`. So you could fix the problem by using

```
def residuals(p, xup, y, dmu):
    xl = np.array([xlambda(p, x) for x in xup])
    return ((y-xl)/dmu)**2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (b != Inf and a != -Inf):
```

This is trying to perform a Python `if` operation, but `(b != Inf and a != -Inf)` is returning an array of boolean values, rather than one `True/False` value.  If this was your own code you could add `np.any(...)` to combine the values.  But in this context I suspect that problem is that either `a` or `b` is an array, when it should be a scalar.

Can you trace those values back up the calling stack?

There have been many SO questions regarding this type of error message.

Comment: Yes, you have right. `b` is an array but the upper value of this integral have to take from an array. For each value the `b` is given by the value from array z

Comment: Then your function has to be written in a way that handles that `z` array, while taking into account that `quad` expects a scalar.